# String date to NSDate with 2 different string data

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, swift

I'm working with an API who send me 2 types of dates (yeah, this is awful ...). I'm dealing with `"2015-03-05T23:18:13+00:00"` and `"2015-03-05T23:18:17Z"` so far, I haven't successfully convert them to a proper `NSDate`here's my try :

```
var date = NSDateFormatter()
var time = "2015-03-05T23:18:17Z"
date.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"
date.dateFromString(time)
```

and

```
var date = NSDateFormatter()
var time ="2015-03-05T23:18:13+00:00"
date.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SS:SS"
date.dateFromString(time)
```

As you can imagine none of both is working. Can you help me ? Is there any proper way to parse this ?

Comment: 24h format, at least "HH".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var fmt = NSDateFormatter()
fmt.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
fmt.dateFormat = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ssZZZZZ"

for time in ["2015-03-05T23:18:17Z", "2015-03-05T23:18:13+00:00"] {
    if let date = fmt.dateFromString(time) {
        println(date)
    }
}
```

`ZZZZZ` can handle both `Z` and `+00:00` format. As for `en_US_POSIX`, see [the document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW7).

Answer (score 1):

First:

```
 date.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"
```

Second:

```
 date.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ'"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, none are working on my `Playground`

Comment: In the simulator works. 2015-03-06 11:07:40.794 HEM[6400:75908] Ver Date: 2015-03-05 23:18:13 +0000